# UItableView footer rendered in header style

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

I'm trying to add a footer to the bottom of my table view. It's a plain style tableView with just 1 section and 1 dynamic prototype cell. I used this method to create the footer:

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (section == 0){
    return @"Section 1 Footer";
}

return nil;

}
```

The result is that the footer is in the correct place, but it looks like a header (grey background with bold font)

It seems to work fine if I switch the table style to Grouped but I don't want this. Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a header for this table. But even if I add one, I still get this problem.

Comment: You forget to create view for footer:     UITableViewHeaderFooterView *sectionFooter = [self.tableview footerViewForSection:0];
[sectionFooter.contentView addSubview:self.myFooterView]; Also don't forgot implement -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Is "viewForFooterInSection" necessary though if I'm already using "titleForFooterInSection"?

Answer (score 2):

Set the tableView style to group. This will change the footer style.